# Android studio design for layout is not showing

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

Android Studio design for layout is not showing if I use TextInputLayout.

Before it was working. I don't update anything. If I remove the TextInputLayout then it is working.

I clean the Invalid cache.

I don't have any idea where is the problem.
What I can do now?

```html
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Withdrawal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView11"
        android:layout_width="159dp"
        android:layout_height="159dp"
        android:src="@drawable/eggs_basket"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.094"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Share with your friend your code to earn Coin"
        android:textColor="#AE6F03"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView11"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.042" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/myRef"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="myCode"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.104"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView6"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.103" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Your Code is:"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.119"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.106" />

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="9dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageView11"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="mu" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is my xml code. After inpute the TextInputEditText it not working.

Comment: Please share your current layout xml and a screenshot of your current layout preview window when using `TextInputLayout` which could help others know your problem better.

Comment: Can you please check now?

Comment: Your layout works fine from my testing and I can see the layout preview. Try clicking "Toggle the visibility of issue panel` button in the layout preview panel to see any error here: https://imgur.com/a/uqKmANy